# How do I ask beamer to use the same color for the \begin{example} block as is being used for the begin{theorem} block?

Tags: beamer

I'm using the Warsaw theme and everything is fine except I don't like the green color that is used for the example block. How can I set it to be the same as that used for the theorem environment block?

Here is a code sample.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Warsaw}



  \setbeamercovered{invisible}
}

\definecolor{UBCblue}{rgb}{0.04706, 0.13725, 0.26667} % UBC Blue (primary)
\definecolor{UBCgrey}{rgb}{0.3686, 0.5255, 0.6235} % UBC Grey (secondary)

\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{bg=UBCblue,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{bg=UBCblue,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{bg=UBCblue,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{bg=UBCblue,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=UBCblue} 
\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=UBCblue} 


\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=false]
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{\pgfsetfillopacity{0.8}}{\pgfsetfillopacity{1}}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=UBCblue}


\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{%
    \usebeamerfont{footline}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
    \hspace{1em}%
    \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
}

\usepackage[english]{babel}


\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts}  
\usepackage{latexsym} 
\usepackage[all,arc]{xy}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{amstext}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{color}   %May be necessary if you want to color links
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true, %set true if you want colored links
    linktoc=all,     %set to all if you want both sections and subsections linked
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black,
    citecolor=black,  %choose some color if you want links to stand out
}

\usepackage{xypic}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newtheorem*{Proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem*{keylemma}{Key Lemma}
\newtheorem*{Remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem*{question}{Question}
\newtheorem*{Task}{Task}
\newtheorem*{cor}{Corollary}
\newtheorem*{thm}{Theorem}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{Theorem}
This is a theorem.
\end{Theorem}
\begin{Remark}
This is a remark.
\end{Remark}
\begin{Example}
This is an example. I don't like this color.
\end{Example}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

You will get the output:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you provide a small example document with the Warsaw theme and the two types of block? That makes it easier for potential answerers to provide a solution.

Comment: @Marijn I will do that in one minute. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usecolortheme{orchid}

\setbeamercolor{block title example}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!75!black}
\setbeamercolor{block body example}{parent=normal text,use=block title,bg=block title.bg!10!bg}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{theorem}
  content...
  \end{theorem}

  \begin{example}
  content...
  \end{example}

\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

---

or with the not so minimal example from your question:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Warsaw}



  \setbeamercovered{invisible}
}

\definecolor{UBCblue}{rgb}{0.04706, 0.13725, 0.26667} % UBC Blue (primary)
\definecolor{UBCgrey}{rgb}{0.3686, 0.5255, 0.6235} % UBC Grey (secondary)

\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{bg=UBCblue,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{bg=UBCblue,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{bg=UBCblue,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{bg=UBCblue,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=UBCblue} 
\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=UBCblue} 


\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=false]
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{\pgfsetfillopacity{0.8}}{\pgfsetfillopacity{1}}
\addtobeamertemplate{block example begin}{\pgfsetfillopacity{0.8}}{\pgfsetfillopacity{1}}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=UBCblue}


\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{%
    \usebeamerfont{footline}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
    \hspace{1em}%
    \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
}

\usepackage[english]{babel}


\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts}  
\usepackage{latexsym} 
\usepackage[all,arc]{xy}
\usepackage{comment}
%\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{wasysym}
%\usepackage{slashbox}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{sagetex}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{amstext}

%\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{filecontents}
%\usepackage{color}   %May be necessary if you want to color links
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true, %set true if you want colored links
    linktoc=all,     %set to all if you want both sections and subsections linked
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black,
    citecolor=black,  %choose some color if you want links to stand out
}

\usepackage{xypic}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{ulem}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newtheorem*{Proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem*{keylemma}{Key Lemma}
\newtheorem*{Remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem*{question}{Question}
\newtheorem*{Task}{Task}
\newtheorem*{cor}{Corollary}
\newtheorem*{thm}{Theorem}


\setbeamercolor{block title example}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!75!black}
\setbeamercolor{block body example}{parent=normal text,use=block title,bg=block title.bg!10!bg}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{Theorem}
This is a theorem.
\end{Theorem}
\begin{Remark}
This is a remark.
\end{Remark}
\begin{Example}
This is an example. I don't like this color.
\end{Example}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Some comments:

- please don't load the same package multiple times
- you don't need

  ```
  \usepackage{enumerate}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{etoolbox}
  \usepackage{color}   
  \usepackage{hyperref}
  ```

  with beamer

Comment: Thank you. There is a slight difference, however. The example title color is blue now, not gray.

Comment: @H.H. You did not show us any code when I answered.

Comment: Oh, I assumed you answered after you saw my code. But anyway, your edit fixed the issue and I'm very grateful for your help.